# workflow sends mail to individual, but not to group

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010, which sends an email when a SharePoint Server 2010 announcement is added or modified. It works as expected when the email only uses my address. However, it does not send mail at all when the email address uses an AD group or a SharePoint group.

I don't want to hard code the addresses. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, we can't send the mail to all users, those are present in the group.
If the SharePoint Group or Ad Group has the Group Email, then the email sent the mail to group email Id.

If you want the email individually means, just iterate the user and send the email to users.

Comment: Thanks for the info. When you say to iterate through the users in the group, is that possible within Designer, or would I need to create the workflow in Visual Studio?

Comment: Check the following link, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/65e5dfc7-626b-47f0-bf56-b58a08219db7 . There is no OOB workflow activities available in SharePoint Designer to iterate Users from SPGroup. So we have to create a Custom activity to use in SharePoint Designer or we have to create a workflow in Visual Studio.

Comment: I think I understand. I hope you don't mind if I paraphrase for others' benefit: SharePoint workflows won't send mail to members of an AD group. If the SharePoint group has an email address, then mail will be sent to that address. Otherwise, you have to create a SharePoint group and populate it with users, and have the workflow send mail to that SharePoint group.

Comment: Also one quick clarification - in my testing, the workflow would not send email to a group that had a group email address. The only way I got it to work was creating a SharePoint group, adding the individual users, and sending to that SharePoint group. But, at least I didn't have to hard code the usernames in the workflow itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether your group has atleast read permissions on the announcement list?

There is also an additional setting in the group settings which could cause this problem. Go to Site Settings -> People and groups -> Your group settings -> You need to select an option which says that the members in this group are accessible to everyone.

Comment: Group has contribute permissions. I changed the setting so everyone can view group members, but that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Check out what Ashish Patel has provided a solution for a similar situation. - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow