# email action in workflow using AD groups

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, email, ad

We're using Sharepoint Foundation 2013. I have a workflow (2010 workflow) which will send an email when some1 adds something to the list. Tried it both ways - add the AD group to the email action in the workflow and tried to add the SP group with the AD group inside into the email action in the workflow, but none of it seems to work. Only if i add AD users one by one to the SP group it send the email. And thats not the way we want to proceed.

Comment: Is the AD group an email distribution list?

Comment: No the AD group is not in email distribution list. But if i add user from the AD to the email action one by one it send them the email. So i guess it should work with AD groups the same way. Isn't it?

Comment: No it wont work if the group has no email associated with it.

Comment: Don't know if i got it. The workflow is not able to get emails from the users in the AD group?

Comment: Have you figured out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the SharePoint Group or Ad Group has the Group Email, then the email sent the mail to group email Id.

There is no Out of the box way to achieve this.

Some possible workarounds

[workflow sends mail to individual, but not to group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25986/workflow-sends-mail-to-individual-but-not-to-group)

[Definitive answer to sending emails to SP Group from Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow)

Comment: We want to send the email to every1 in the AD group. The group have not a single email as a group. For example the group is called Test and inside the group we have users Test1, Test2, Test3... with individual emails. And to that emails it should send the email.