# Email error but task email works

Tags: email

I've built  a workflow in VS. The wf contains a 'Create Task' and assigned to a group. When I run the wf an email is recieved and all works.

I then added a 'send email' actitivity and used the following parameters in the code block :

```
SendEmailResponse.To = "Credit Approvers";

SendEmailResponse.From = @"somecompany\itmanager";

SendEmailResponse.Subject = "Expense Report Approved";

SendEmailResponse.Body = "Your Expense Report: ";
```

Now when I run I always get an error :

The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.

I've also tried specific email addresses rather than groups but continue to get this message. I've tried various corelation tokens also.

If I get the email through ' create task' then could a problem still exist with the out-going email settings as in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I have generally observed that when Task emails work, the emails configuration is fine but there could be an issue with sending emails to a SharePoint Group.

As far as sending emails to SharePoint group is concerned, I had similar question and I ended up writing a custom activity which outputs email addresses of group members in an output variable: [Definitive answer to sending emails to SP Group from Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow)

Comment: Hi
I've also tried individuals also, this doesn’t work either.