# sending email to a sharepoint group

Tags: email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definitive answer to sending emails to SP Group from Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow)

Hi I've set up a wf in VS and want to send an email to a sharepoint group.
I've created a sharepoint group and added it to a site, and is populated with users.
Then I've added a create emali activity and added the group name to the 'To' properties.
No emails are recieved. If I unstead use a single email address i.e tom@mysite.com in the 'To' field it works.

Could someome advise what the issue could be pls ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this and found a solution that worked for me. Check below

[Definitive answer to sending emails to SP Group from Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow)

Let me know if you want me to share the code of my activity.