# Workflow 2013 Task assigning and emailing to SharePoint 2013 Groups?

Tags: 2013, workflow, email, groups, tasks

Just to confirm..

Is it possible to use a workflow 2013 to Assign a Task to a SharePoint 2013 Group?

Is it possible to email a SharePoint 2013 Group from Workflow 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating AD group and than instead of a username you put AD group name.
That is how we did this for alerts and some other notifications.

and answer to your question is yes, you can send an email to group.
here is a topic about it:
[Definitive answer to sending emails to SP Group from Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/definitive-answer-to-sending-emails-to-sp-group-from-workflow)

Comment: So without custom code, you can't email or assign a task to a SharePoint group in 2013 from Workflow 2013?

Comment: Also wondering if that coded solution in the link you provided is possible on o365 SharePoint Online 2013?

Comment: I am not sure. I found that explanation when I was in search for answer like you. But than we decided it is better to create AD group.